# Is possible to allow user to login with different role?

Tags: users, login, wp-login-form, user-roles

Is it possible to allow users to log in with a different role?

For eg. I've one user having two roles one is "Mentor" and second is "Mentee" with different access on the front end.

And now I want to create login where a user can select a role to log in with. If the user will select "Mentor" will able to access all feature this role and vice versa. So a user has to select a role to login so they can access website features according to selected role.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, It is possible.

Comment: Can you please let me know how?

Answer (score 0):

When you register a user keep 2 rule as select or radio button, And keep save the rule in the database.
also, keep rule option in login, When the login checks the rule and give what access you want to give.

For access keep a condition in top of each page like 'if user rule == ***' else 'You are not allowed to visit the page'

Comment: registration process already completed, User can select any role to at the time of registration but problem with login using different role and give access of only one role

Comment: it's nothing just keep user information in the session variable.
User ID, Name, Rule
The check in every page or where you want if the rule match he can access.

Comment: multiple roles for one user is possible, eg user will be mentor or mentee both but can't access both role feature with same login. If user need to access Mentor feature then need to login with mentor role and same for mentee

Comment: yes session will be good but I'm looking with wordpress possibility

Comment: Yes possible, then you have to keep the option to choose multiple rules choose